# array passed as parameter issue

Tags: javascript

I've got 2dim array set as global variable populated with numbers on row - 0 and strings on row-1.
But when I passed it as a parameter to a function most of its values modifies into undefined but in one strangely value is kept!?!

```
    function formElements(howMany){ 
        elArr = [];
        var w; var surface;
        for(var j=0; j<howMany; j++){
           w = randomNumber(1,200);
           surface = w*randomNumber(1,100);
           elArr[0] =[j];
           elArr[1] =[j];
           elArr[0][j]=surface;   
           elArr[1][j]='_'+j;
        }
        aFunction(elArr,...other parameters....); //in this function I receive array with these undefined values I mentioned above!!!
    }
    function randomNumber(x,y) {
        return Math.floor((Math.abs(y - x) + 1) * Math.random()) + Math.min(x, y);  
    }
```

Could somebody tell me what's wrong?
10x and BR

Comment: Which array is the global variable?  Where is this function (`formElements`) called?  What is `j`?

Comment: Have you checked the values in the array *before* sending them to your function?  You're referencing variables in your snippet that aren't defined in the snippet, so maybe there are issues with those.

Comment: No I've just edited the code so it's more readable for u and forget a loop I'll edited it just a moment

Comment: @kidwon: Some advice...  When posting a question post as much detail as you can.  Removing the loop drastically changes the question here.

Comment: Yeah you're quite right but that wasn't on purpose I've got other code in that function which doesn't affect the array and by mistake I've deleted the loop either

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The references to `j` make it look like this is inside a loop.  In which case, I don't think this is doing what you want:

```
elArry[0] = [j];
```

This sets the value of `elArray[0]` to an array with a single element, `j`.  If you're doing that inside your loop then you're overwriting the arrays every time with a new one with a single element.

EDIT:

And now that you've posted the full loop that's verified.  You probably want something like:

```
function formElements(howMany){ 
    elArr = [[],[]];
    for(var j=0; j<howMany; j++){
       elArr[0][j]=surface;   
       elArr[1][j]='_'+j;
    }
    aFunction(elArr,...other parameters....);
}
```

Comment: +1 additionally it might be easier to understand as a 1-dim array containing objects like `{ number: surface, string: '_' + j }`. But with more meaningful names than `number` and `string` of course.

Comment: 10x that really helped!I was trying to avoid 'new Array()' thing but didn't know the right syntax of the alternative.